# Android GCM registration launches different services

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Trying to migrate from C2DM to GCM service on Android.

Faced one problem. When sending the registration intent, I get the following services launched:

- On ver. 2.3.5 - 'Could to Device Messaging' and 'Google Messaging Service'
- On ver. 4.0.4 - 'Google Messaging Service'
- On ver. 2.3.3 - 'Cloud to Device Messaging' and 'Google Messaging Service'

> Using real devices

Tried using the following code:

```
    Intent registrationIntent = new Intent(
            "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
    registrationIntent.putExtra("app",
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(), 0));
    registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", SENDER_ID_NUMBER);
    this.context.startService(registrationIntent);
```

and

```
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(context);
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(context);
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(context);
    if (regId.equals("")) {
      GCMRegistrar.register(this.context, SENDER_ID_NUMBER);
    } else {
      Log.v("gcm_registration", "Already registered");
    }
```

**EDIT:**
After setting up a local server and using the simulation of Google gcm i found out that:

- On ver. 2.3.5 - i do not get gcm message
- On ver. 4.0.4 - i get gcm message
- On ver. 2.3.3 - i get gcm message

**EDIT2:**
After a little more testing I found the following:
As I have described above about which version of Android OS runs which service, so these services are started if I restart the phone and turn on network
Now, if I turn of all of(stop) the Google Services on the phone and send the registration intent: `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER`, then:

- On ver. 2.3.5 - 'Could to Device Messaging' is started
- On ver. 4.0.4 - 'Google Messaging Service' is started
- On ver. 2.3.3 - 'Cloud to Device Messaging' is started

Which makes it impossible to send notifications to those devices, where 'Cloud to Device Messaging' is started.

*Questions:*

Does that mean that my application has to support both C2DM and GCM?

Why in the nutshell does this happen and how to avoid such a behavior?

Why Google Services launches different services on the GCM registration intent?

Comment: Why did you expect the service name to stay the same? As long as it responds to the right intents, the service name and identity is an implementation detail that you shouldn't rely upon.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev It is not about the name, but rather functionality that matters here. Basically the difference is in the C2DM and GCM, since mine ver. 4.0.4 is the only one that receives intents, ver. 2.3.5. does not receive intents (in my opinion because one service blocks another), and ver. 2.3.3. Does not receive anything because it is purely C2DM service